# PITest hangs at start of test run

Tags: java, maven, pitest

I'm trying to run PITest on the master version of light4j (https://github.com/networknt/light-4j), a project I selected more or less at random to try out PITest on real world code.

The test completed fine on most modules, except for the 'cient' module of light4j. When running

```
mvn -X test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage
```

In the light-4j/client folder the normal unit test run completes (all tests are ok, 3 skipped), but PITest doesn't seem to generate and execute mutations. The last messages are

```
[INFO] Adding org.pitest:pitest to SUT classpath
[INFO] Mutating from /Users/jan/dev/inno/light-4j/client/target/classes
[INFO] Defaulting target classes to match packages in build directory
/-\|/-\|/-\|/-\|/-stderr  : WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2 (file:/Users/jan/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.8.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.8.Final.jar) to constructor sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorstderr  : Provider()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in astderr  :  future release
```

And nothing happens after that.

The normal build of light4j completes successfully.

What could be the problem?

[edit on Feb 5th, 2020:
I've forked the light4j repo: https://github.com/jvermeir/light-4j
Then I executed a normal build `mvn clean install` so all artifacts are in my local maven repository.
Next I changed the pom.xml at the root level of the light4j project, adding

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>
    <artifactId>pitest-maven</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.10</version>
    <dependencies>
<!--                    <dependency>-->
<!--                        <groupId>org.pitest</groupId>-->
<!--                        <artifactId>pitest-junit5-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                        <version>0.10</version>-->
<!--                    </dependency>-->
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

in the build section 
Finally I executed the tests with PiTest enabled from the client folder: `mvn -X test org.pitest:pitest-maven:mutationCoverage > ../buildlog.txt`
This results in a build.txt file, but also in a couple of lines that show up in the terminal:

```
17:10:30 PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
17:10:30 PIT >> INFO : Sending 147 test classes to minion
17:10:30 PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
17:10:30 PIT >> INFO : MINION : 17:10:30 PIT >> INFO : Checking environment

17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : MINION : 17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : Found  18 tests

17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : MINION : 17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0

17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : MINION : 17:10:32 PIT >> INFO : 18 tests received

17:10:33 PIT >> INFO : MINION : WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl (file:/Users/jan/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/2.0.2/powermock-reflect-2.0.2.jar) to method java
17:10:33 PIT >> INFO : MINION : .lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access
17:10:33 PIT >> INFO : MINION :  operations will be denied in a future release

17:11:24 PIT >> INFO : MINION : 17:11:24 PIT >> WARNING : More threads at end of test (46) com.networknt.client.Http2ClientTest than start. (5)

17:11:24 PIT >> INFO : Calculated coverage in 54 seconds.
17:11:25 PIT >> INFO : Created  92 mutation test units
```

The end of build.txt looks like this:

```
[INFO] Adding org.pitest:pitest to SUT classpath
[INFO] Mutating from /Users/jan/dev/inno/light4jfork/light-4j/client/target/classes
[INFO] Defaulting target classes to match packages in build directory
-stderr  : WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2 (file:/Users/jan/.m2/repository/org/jboss/xnio/xnio-nio/3.3.8.Final/xnio-nio-3.3.8.Final.jar) to constructor sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorstderr  : Provider()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.xnio.nio.NioXnio$2
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in astderr  :  future release
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same and it stops at the client module. I am just wondering if we should add pitest-maven plugin to the pom.xml

```
[INFO] Mutating from /home/steve/networknt/light-4j/client/target/classes
[INFO] Defaulting target classes to match packages in build directory
7:35:54 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Verbose logging is disabled. If you encounter a problem, please enable it before reporting an issue.
7:35:54 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Sending 147 test classes to minion
7:35:54 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Sent tests to minion
7:35:54 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : 7:35:54 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Checking environment

7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : 7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Found  18 tests

7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : 7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : Dependency analysis reduced number of potential tests by 0

7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : 7:35:55 p.m. PIT >> INFO : 18 tests received

7:35:56 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl (file:/home/steve/.m2/repository/org/powermock/powermock-reflect/2.0.2/powermock-reflect-2.0.2.jar) to method jav
7:35:56 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : a.lang.Object.clone()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal acces
7:35:56 p.m. PIT >> INFO : MINION : s operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: thanks for trying. My second attempt at PiTest failed as well, see updated question above. I was thinking that maybe the client test just takes too much time? I've forked the repo here https://github.com/jvermeir/light-4j so we can do some experimenting.

Comment: When testing the client, we need to test the OAuth 2.0 token expiration and timing. So there are a lot of parallel processes in waiting states. That is why it takes a lot of time. There are even more integration test cases are not running in the normal build process to ensure there is no threading issue with concurrent requests. HTTP/2 is more complicated as it allows multiplex and it is a huge advantage compare with HTTP/1.1.  Is there any way we can skip this module?

Comment: I was afraid that would be the problem. I guess in cases like this I could run PiTest on each sub module and skip the ones that take too much time.